# Android - Placing a ListView in Preferences Page

Tags: android, listview, preferences

I have a preferences page in my application. As there is no Multiple Choice ListPreference (There's one after API Level 11) I want to put a ListView at preferences page. But the preferences.xml doesn't let me to insert a Linear Layout.

**Here's my preferences.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="Auto Refresh Settings">
                <CheckBoxPreference
                        android:title="Auto Refresh"
                        android:defaultValue="false"
                        android:summary="Enable / Disable Auto Refresh"
                        android:key="checkboxPref" />
                <ListPreference
                        android:title="Auto Refresh Frequency"
                        android:summary="Select the frequency of Auto Refresh"
                        android:key="listPref"
                        android:defaultValue="20"
                        android:entries="@array/listArray"
                        android:entryValues="@array/listValues" />
        </PreferenceCategory>

        </PreferenceScreen>
```

**This is how it looks:**

[image: preferences.xml graphical layout]

**What I want**:

[image: whatiwant]:

**Lastly my Settings.java (preferences):**

```
package com.sarkolata.coding;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceCategory;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity
{


     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


          final Preference ListPref = (Preference) findPreference("listPref");
          final Preference CheckPref = (Preference) findPreference("checkboxPref");


          if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).getBoolean("checkboxPref", false)) {
              ListPref.setEnabled(false);
          }

          ListPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                Main.update_tick = Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString()) * 1000;

                return true;
            }
        });



          CheckPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                if(newValue.toString() == "true")
                {
                    ListPref.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    ListPref.setEnabled(true);
                }

                if(newValue.toString() == "true") {

                Main.refreshAllServers(Main.context, Main.bcontext,"start");

                } else {

                    Main.refreshAllServers(Main.context, Main.bcontext,"stop");

                }

                return true;
            }
        });

     }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if is is clever to add a ListView inside a preference pane because the PreferenceActivity already uses a ListView to show the many preferences. Perhaps you want  to use a [MultiSelectListPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/MultiSelectListPreference.html), preference that allows you to do multiple selection.  You can see an example at http://blog.350nice.com/wp/archives/240

Comment: MultiSelectListPreference is Since API Level 11.
And I think that the method specified at http://blog.350nice.com/wp/archives/240 is not inside the preferences page. I need it in preferences page, because having two preferences pages wouldn't be good.